# Issues when adding devise-jwt to a existente User model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im trying to add the devise-jwt to an existent app I have. Im adding API endpoints now, and want to use the same Model I have already

I added the gem devise-jwt following this article here: https://medium.com/@mazik.wyry/rails-5-api-jwt-setup-in-minutes-using-devise-71670fd4ed03

I had configured my devise.rb file with:

```
config.jwt do |jwt|
  jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
  jwt.dispatch_requests = [
    ['POST', %r{^/login$}]
  ]
  jwt.revocation_requests = [
    ['DELETE', %r{^/logout$}]
  ]
  jwt.expiration_time = 1.day.to_i
end
```

Had created my jwt_blacklist.rb and migrations for it:

```
class CreateJwtBlacklist < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :jwt_blacklist do |t|
      t.string :jti, null: false
    end
    add_index :jwt_blacklist, :jti
  end
end

class JWTBlacklist < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Blacklist

  self.table_name = 'jwt_blacklist'
end
```

When I try to add those lines to my user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook],
        :jwt_authenticatable,
        jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTBlacklist
```

And when I try to start my server im getting:

```
/Users/fmaymone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport- 
6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load': /booksculp/app/models/user.rb:6: 
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => (SyntaxError)
    :jwt_authenticatable ,
```

Someone knows what Im doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change your `User` model to the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
        :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTBlacklist, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
```